# Opencv fisheye undistort without checker board approach

Tags: opencv, distortion, fisheye

I am looking if there is any way we can identify the camera calibration matrix and others to undistort a fisheye image without the checkerboard approach in OpenCV. This is because my current setup doesn't allow me to take some sample pictures out of it. So required an alternative approach. Preferably using OpenCV (Python). Thanks in advance.

Comment: checkerboard aproach uses 'findChessboardCorners'. run findChessboardCorners once every few frames or so. If it is succesfull you can run the calibration, if it is not, you don't run the calibration. This way you don't need take sample pictures.

Comment: but in my case, it is not detecting corners since I have only a single image available, hence the chessboard approach fails.

Comment: When you have a lot of 2D/3D correspondences, you can just run the calibrateCamera with them.

Comment: make a gui with namedWindow, slap some trackbars on it for the most important camera intrinsics, imshow an undistorted picture and fiddle with the parameters until you like the result

Answer (score 0):

Recently there are some AI approches using a single image. E.g. https://github.com/alexvbogdan/DeepCalib.

But I never tried and don't know if it works.